# How to calculate page values in Google Analytics 4?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio, google-analytics-4

I run the website with ads. Ads are rotating. Each Ad has its click value.
So, when a visitor clicks on an ad, I send an ad click event with the value information.

Like:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'top_ad_click',
    'value': value,
    'partner': partner,
    'product': product,
});
```

I want to create the report table in Data Studio with page URLs and the sum of the "value" for each page. How can I do that?

I tried to create a report with Full Page Url as dimension and SUM(Event value) as metric, but it doesn't work:  Re-aggregating metrics is not supported.